# Файлы загружаются на компьютер вместо исполнения

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Есть конфиг `.htaccess`, который нужно перевести в nginx:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Воспользовался [конвертером](https://winginx.com/ru/htaccess) и получился следующий конфиг:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
  }
}
```

Вставил этот отрывок кода в свой nginx-конфиг, где уже настроен PHP-FPM:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

И теперь файлы просто загружаются на компьютер вместо исполнения. Уже пробовал гуглить и перепробовал все возможные способы. Ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

вот так попробуйте

`location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 }`